# Show that H/K is isomorphic to $Z_2 \oplus Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

We are given $H = \{(1),(13),(24),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23),(1234),(1432)\}$ is a subgroup of $S_4$. Also assume $K = \{(1),(13)(24)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. Show $H/K$ isomorphic to $Z_2\oplus Z_2$.

This is just a practice question (not assignment). So I have tried finding $H/K$ explicitly.

$H/K = \{\{(1),(13)(24)\},\{(13),(24)\},\{(14)(23),(12)(34)\},\{(1234),(1423)\}\}$. We know there are only $2$ groups of order $4$. One of the elements in $H/K$ we see is $(1234)K$, doesn't this element have a order of $4$, making $H/K$ cyclic and hence not isomorphic to $Z_2\oplus Z_2$?

Comment: Do you mean $S_{4}$, not $S_{3}$?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry about that, editing question.

Comment: No, the square of that element is $(13)(24)$, which is in $K$.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see what you mean! So the order of (1234)K is actually 2 not 4?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem, I will answer my own question below, I think that is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - be careful. $(1234)^2 = (13)(24) \in K$. Hence, $(1234)K^2 = K$, so $(1234)K$ has order 2 in $H/K$. In fact, you can just check by hand that all the elements of $H$ either square to $(1)$ or to $(13)(24)$ [You need to use the fact that disjoint cycles commute]. Hence, every element of $H/K$ has order $\leq 2$, which means $H/K$ has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 4):

After Tobias comment. I realized the order of (1234)K is actually 2 and not 4. Since 
(1234)K(1234)K = (1234)(1234)K = (13)(24)K = K. We know there are only 2 groups of order 4. That is $Z_4$ and $Z_2 \bigoplus Z_2$. Since we see $H/K$ does not have any elements of order 4 it is not cyclic and cannot be isomorphic to $Z_4$, hence $H/K$ must be isomorphic to $Z_2 \bigoplus Z_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your doubt about these two being isomorphic has been solved but just in case you still don't see how to define a precise isomorphism between them note that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \bigoplus  \mathbb{Z}_2 $ has two generators, namley $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ also $(1,0) + (0,1) = (1,1)$. Therefore I think it's very easy for you to know what precisely your isomorphism should be and which coset should be send to which generator. You can also use the fact that there are only two groups of order 4 up to isomorphism as you already pointed out.

Comment: Wait I thought the group $Z_2 \bigoplus Z_2$ was not cyclic since gcd(2,2) not 1. So how can we have generators?

Comment: How can it be obvious when any choice that sends the identity to the identity works?

Comment: @user77404 $G=\langle(1,0) , (0,1) \rangle$ That's what I mean. A group is cyclic if it can be generated by one element. But you can't generate $\mathbb{Z}_2 \bigoplus  \mathbb{Z}_2$ only by one element, you'll need two. This kind of groups are called finitely generated as you possibly know.

Comment: Ohh right, good point!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: When you have two isomorphic groups you can construct an isomorphism between them by defining which generator should be mapped to which generator in the other group. Here, both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ can be chosen as you mentioned, but it doesn't mean that you can't construct an isomorphism that way. It only means you'll have more freedom in the construction. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But you claimed that what you wrote made it obvious how to construct the isomorphism. But in fact there are $6$ ways of constructing it, and none of them seem more obvious than the others.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: What I claimed is that by considering the generators it will be obvious how you can construct 'an' isomorphism. I didn't mean there is only one way to construct 'the' isomorphism. I'm sorry if it sounded that way, but I don't know any better way to reword my phrase. If you have any suggestions tell me and I'll edit my post to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I just don't see how your answer says anything about how to construct an isomorphism. As I already remarked, you can basically not fail in doing this, so I don't see how it helps to consider the generators.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Then maybe you should try to show that the set of non-singular matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ and then you'll see that considering the generators do help. And it won't be so trivial to find an explicit isomorphism in that case and you can indeed fail if you do it randomly. But I doubt that is what you mean, I think you have problem with my phrasing of my sentence or something like that.

Comment: Obviously it is sometimes useful to consider a suitable set of generators in order to find an isomorphism. But this is not about a general case. The question and everything you mention in the answer is about this very special case where it does not help at all. As to the example you mention, I disagree that it is a case where considering generators is useful, as it is a non-abelian Group of order $6$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: This is what I'm saying: If we want to show $G$ and $G'$ are isomorophic we should find a bijective homomorphism between every elements of them. I'm claiming that in the case where we know the generators for each group we can make the problem easier by restricting our isomorphism to the generators. The other elements don't really matter because other elements are obtained by multiplication of the generators and our isomorphism preserves the multiplication laws of both groups.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10064/discussion-between-tobias-kildetoft-and-some1-new4u)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Unfortunately I can't come to chat at the moment, but my e-mail is some1.new4u{at}yahoo{dot}com. We can discuss it over there.